# Select or eliminate indices from vector array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am writing a code, where I want to check a `vector array` elements and check if the present element equal the previous `x(m)=x(m+1)`, then delete it , if not keep it in the array ... How to do that?

Here, what I tried to do:

```
vg=vg1(441777:448207);

j=zeros(size(vg));

for m=1:6431;
    if m+1<6432
        if vg(m)==vg(m+1)
            j(m)=[];
        else
            j(m)=vg(m);
        end
    end
end
```

But it is not working and it gives error,, So may I know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely because you are actively removing elements from `j` within your loop and then trying to access those elements later. You should instead just have `j` full of `NaN` values and then remove the `NaN` values at the end.

```
j = nan(size(vg));

% Go ahead and keep the first value
j(1) = vg(1);

% Just start at 2 and look backwards rather than using an if statement
% every time through the loop
for m = 2:numel(vg)
    % Only change the value in j to a number if it's new
    if vg(m - 1) ~= vg(m)
        j(m) = vg(m);
    end
end

% Remove all of the NaN values (the duplicates)
j = j(~isnan(j));
```

A better vectorized approach would be to use `diff` to compute the differences between successive elements and identify where there are different numbers (`diff` result is `~= 0`) and keep only those elements by using the output of `diff(values) ~= 0` as a logical index into `values`.

```
values = [1 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 1 2 2];
result = values([true, diff(values) ~= 0]);
%     1     2     3     4     5     1     2
```

Note that we have to prepend `true` to the beginning of the output of `diff(values) ~= 0` since we will want to always include the first element.

Answer (score 0):

The code above possible will not work, since length of vector j changes inside the loop. So, on some step m bigger then length(j), which rises error.

Also, the for loop in matlab is very slow, therefore matrix form computations are preferable (and clear).

```
vg = [1 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 1 2 2]; 
df = [1 diff(vg)];
vg(df == 0) = [];
```